# C# API OAuth Consumption

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, rest

I have been provided an API with the base URL and the Authentication URL. This API makes use of token authentication. I have written code to authenticate then pass the token to the other URL but keep running into the error below:

`Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.'`

My code is as below

```
    public string Index()
    {
        var accessToken = string.Empty;
        string URL = "https://api.mkoinapp.net/apps/merchants/api/v1/auth/apps/authenticate/";
        string _user = "XX";
        string _pwd = "XX";
        string _clientId = "XXX";
        string _clientSecret = "XXXX";

        var KeyValus = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", _user),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", _pwd),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", _clientId),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", _clientSecret)
            };
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, URL + "access_token");

        request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(KeyValus);

        var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;

        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
            var json = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            JObject jwtDynamic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
            // List<Token> jwtDynamic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Token>>(json);
            var accessTokenExpiration = jwtDynamic.Value<DateTime>("expires_in");
            accessToken = jwtDynamic.Value<string>("access_token");
            var name = jwtDynamic.Value<string>("name");
            var accessexpirationDate = accessTokenExpiration;
            Response.Redirect("https://api.mkoinapp.net/apps/merchants/api/v1/iprs?id=" + _user);
        }

        return accessToken;
    }
```

Any help to resolve this will be apprciated.

Comment: So, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject probably fails deserializing because what is in your `json` variable isn't really JSON. Did you check what you get back?

Comment: /\ What @Cheesebaron said. I can almost promise you that what you are getting back is HTML telling you that you made the call wrong.

Comment: @Cheesebaron. Below is my response 

    `{
    "status": true,
    "detail": "Login successful",
    "user": {
        "id": 72,
        "username": "minet"
    },
    "auth_details": {
        "access_token": "zcdPdlA6doMmZ77sGtq3za9USLBFoB",
        "expires_in": 604800,
        "token_type": "Bearer",
        "scope": "merchants IPRS",
        "refresh_token": "orqIq8oPUOLpPibPnufkSaZnSEtAr4"
    }
} `

Comment: I have tried with other APIs. The error is still the same

Answer (score 1):

You may be experiencing any of these errors:

1. The response is a bad formatted JSON.
2. The response is not a JSON (could be an HTML as Casey is mentioning or XML).
3. The response is an array, you're trying to parse JObject in that case you're going to need JArray.